# JDO - 1-N unidirectional relation using annotations - Column name?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I'm using JDO (with Datanucleus implementation) for a new project for the first time, and I'm having troubles defining 1-N unidirectional owned relation using JDO annotations. What I need is to have a collection of `Subitems` in an `Item`, such that a `Subitem` doesn't have a reference to the owner:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Item {
    ...
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    Collection<Subitem> subitems;
    ...
}
```

It's all well and good, but how can I define which existing RDBMS column the relation maps to? AFAIK an owned 1-N is realized in a DB by creating a non-nullable **table column** in a child table but I don't have (and don't want) a parent reference **class field** in a `Subitem` which I can then decorate with `@Column(name="...")` annotation.

And how to properly use `@ForeignKey` annotation in JDO3? The annotation accepts the *name* of the FK constraint but not the corresponding FK table and column specification. By definition a FK is a ref. constraint between *two* tables based on a common key, but I can't seem to specify the other table and a common key([@ForeginKey at Datanucleus JDO docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/annotations.html#ForeignKey) ).

Edit:
`@Element(column="...")` annotation should be used instead:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Item {
    ...
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Element(column="itemId")
    Collection<Subitem> subitems;
    ...
}
```

As it's clearly stated in the documentation links in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDO (or JPA too for that matter) doesn't have "owned" relations, just relations (it is a term I've only ever heard of in relation to GAE's datastore, and you're not using that).

DataNucleus docs defines all such relations adequately IMHO so just navigate the menu from where you got to, for example
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#fk_uni

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/constraints.html#fk

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've somehow missed that part of the docs. I've been misled by the actual name of the `@ForeignKey` annotation, where it seems `@Element(column="...")` should be used. All I wonder now is what's the purpose of `@ForeignKey` annotation. :)

Comment: And thank you for great data tools, a proxy-less and predictable detached mode is a godsend for data object's double-duty as a DTO (AND it fits with GWT nicely)!

Comment: The column is not the "foreign-key" in an RDBMS; it is used by the "foreign-key" only. @ForeignKey defines the "foreign-key" itself (its name and how/whether it cascades etc).

Comment: Oh, so it is probably a class attribute then. Makes sense, since FK could be composite and if it were a field annotation it would have to be repeated and would make no sense. Thank you.